# Create a logging system to log user activity in Django

Tags: mysql, django, logging, tracking

I would like to have a functionality to log a user activities after they have been logged into my Django app. The log will consist of user tracking details such as how long a user spent on a webpage, how often the webpage is being served up for the user. Mainly getting details on how popular a certain webpage or data in my Django app so that I could create more content that users prefer. Any ideas or tools to implement this?

Comment: Hello Jax and welcome to SO. I think your question is too generic to be answered. You are requesting a whole package of functionality and techniques that are a lot for a single question. I recommend you break it down to smaller pieces so that we can be able to help you.

Comment: Take a look of `django-activity-stream`, https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. However after researching I managed to find Posthog to be the most suitable. https://github.com/PostHog/posthog